# Collect usings from all enclosing namespaces having an ITypeSymbol

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am writing a class generator using `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis` that takes as input an existing class, i.e. an `ITypeSymbol` instance, and is supposed to generate a new `NamespaceDeclarationSyntax` that contains a `ClassDeclarationSyntax`. Essentially the class being generated is a facade for the source class. That being said, the same set of `using`s and same `namespace` name is required in the generated code for the generated facade class to compile correctly.

I am processing the source code using a custom `CSharpSyntaxRewriter` descendant. The facade generation logic is called from the `VisitClassDeclaration` method. I use `SemanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol` to retrieve the corresponding `ITypeSymbol`.

In order to build a list of all applicable `using`s, and to construct the fully qualified namespace name, I wanted to do the following:

```
// collect usings and construct namespace name
SyntaxList<UsingDirectiveSyntax> allUsings = SyntaxFactory.List<UsingDirectiveSyntax>();
var nmspace = ClassSymbol.ContainingNamespace;
string namespaceName = null;
while (nmspace != null)
{
    if (!nmspace.IsGlobalNamespace)
    {
        if (namespaceName == null)
            namespaceName = nmspace.Name;
        else
            namespaceName = nmspace.Name + "." + namespaceName;
    }

    // here nmspace.DeclaringSyntaxReferences contains all occurrences in the given assembly
    var syntax = nmspace.DeclaringSyntaxReferences.First().GetSyntax();

    if (syntax is NamespaceDeclarationSyntax)
        allUsings = allUsings.AddRange(((NamespaceDeclarationSyntax) syntax).Usings);
    else if (syntax is CompilationUnitSyntax)
        allUsings = allUsings.AddRange(((CompilationUnitSyntax) syntax).Usings);
    nmspace = nmspace.ContainingNamespace;
}
```

The problem is (1) I can't see an easy way to traverse the syntax tree from a given `SyntaxNode` back to the root, and (2) even how to retrieve the one exact `NamespaceDeclarationSyntax` enclosing the given `ClassDeclarationSyntax`.

In the end, I want to construct a new `NamespaceDeclarationSyntax` like this:

```
return SyntaxFactory.NamespaceDeclaration(
    SyntaxFactory.ParseName(namespaceName), 
    SyntaxFactory.List<ExternAliasDirectiveSyntax>(), 
    allUsings, 
    SyntaxFactory.List(new[] {(MemberDeclarationSyntax) generatedClass}));
```

Question: Having any given `SyntaxNode`, how do I traverse the tree back to the root `CompilationUnitSyntax` node?

Comment: Try the Ancestors property on a SyntaxNode

Comment: @Sievajet Yes, that's it! Will you post it as an answer? Also meanwhile I discovered `SyntaxNode.Parent`, which I missed originally due to a misleading compilation error, suggesting it was an internal member.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`Ancestors`](http://source.roslyn.io/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/R/70d1b9c06b5b04c7.html) or [`AncestorsAndSelf`](http://source.roslyn.io/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/R/bec99789f8b3d64d.html) property the retrieve all the parents back up the SyntaxTree.

The code to collect all usings from the given `SyntaxNode` up to the root `CompilationUnitSyntax` then looks like this:

```
// collect usings
SyntaxList<UsingDirectiveSyntax> allUsings = SyntaxFactory.List<UsingDirectiveSyntax>();
foreach (var syntaxRef in ClassSymbol.DeclaringSyntaxReferences)
{
    foreach (var parent in syntaxRef.GetSyntax().Ancestors(false))
    {
        if (parent is NamespaceDeclarationSyntax)
            allUsings = allUsings.AddRange(((NamespaceDeclarationSyntax)parent).Usings);
        else if (parent is CompilationUnitSyntax)
            allUsings = allUsings.AddRange(((CompilationUnitSyntax)parent).Usings);
    }
}
```